# NSSet with what looks like a protocol (NSSet<NSObject *> *name)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsset

I have generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses (`Photographer` and `Photo`) using the data model editor - they have a `Photographer` ->To-Many-> `Photo` relationship.

`Photographer` (CoreDataProperties) category came with a property:

```
@interface Photographer (CoreDataProperties)

...
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Photo *>  *photos;

@end
```

What does `NSSet<Photo*>` mean? Can you specify what type of objects should be in an `NSSet` using protocol-like notation? Can't find any info about it in the documentation or anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, NSSet is a generic type, so it needs an element type to be supplied in order for its type to be completely defined for the compiler; the <Photo *> is part of its type signature.  To the compiler, Array<String> = [String].  You can initialize an array of strings with the sytanx Array<String>() as well as [String](). Check out the discussion of generic types here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html (I know this is Swift rather than objective C, but I believe the concept is the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 7, Apple has added 'Lightweight Generics' to Objective C.

They will generate compiler warnings if there is a type mismatch.

> Objective-C declarations of NSArray, NSSet and NSDictionary types
>   using lightweight generic parameterization are imported by Swift with
>   information about the type of their contents preserved.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it was Xcode 7 specific. So generally it's only a compiler warning thing, you still can pass any type of objects to it, just the compiler will warn about the type you declared with the property?

Comment: You could, but I would suggest it would be better to remove the generics code and just use NSSet *photos;, then you don't need to ignore any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This was added recently for Swift/Objective-C interoperation.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html and look for "generics".